# I want to post data and display the http response send by the server on the browser but i am stuck on browser nothing is displayed

Tags: jquery, html, post, http-post

I want to post data and display the http response send by the server on the browser but i am stuck on browser nothing is displayed

I checked through wire shark that server is sending json response but nothing is displayed on browser and i want to fetch response body and parse it and then display it to the user .

And is there is any way to fetch form details and then wrap it on variable and post it to the server

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("button").click(function(){
                $.post(
                    "http://192.168.0.135:8080/uid",
                    {
                        "type" : "CREATE_ACCOUNT",
                        "data" : '{ "hardwareID" : "SAM1234567890123", "name" : "Jain", "emailID" : "jain@gmail.com", "password" : "dgbedbeifkfk" }'
                    },
                    function(data,status) {
                        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
                    }
                );
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <button>Send an HTTP POST request to a page and get the result back</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thing is you can send any json to server..ur issue is sending json inside json...like data has another json string...

Comment: Did you have a look with Developer Tools like Firebug, what comes back when you do the $.post() ?

Comment: I am getting JavaScript Object Notation: application/json as my response

Comment: My response from server is Content-Type: application/json){
"data": {},
"type": "CHANGE_PASSWORD",
"result": {
"status": 401,
"message": "Unauthorized - Session ID is invalid."
}-
}   which is json so how do i fetch this response from server and display it to the browser

Comment: 'data' should be that object then..

Comment: any answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

Just to let you know, your JSON is not valid, this is the correct version of your JSON:

```
{
    "type": "CREATE_ACCOUNT",
    "data": {
        "hardwareID": "SAM1234567890123",
        "name": "Jain",
        "emailID": "jain@gmail.com",
        "password": "dgbedbeifkfk"
    }
}
```

Remove the ' in front of the { in you "data" row.

I highly recommend you to **validate** your JSON via [jsonLint.com](http://jsonlint.com/) before you are searching for other errors.

Comment: Yes i know that and it is not the problem....what i am asking is how to display json (response)